# PCRE - когда использовать модификатор 'u'?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Работаю с utf-8 кодировкой. В справочных изданиях (Джеффри Фридл - Регулярные выражения 2008, Котеров - PHP 7 2016) упоминается, что для работы с данной кодировкой применяется модификатор `u`. Как показала практика, да и многие примеры регулярок тут на SO, регулярки в php работают и без данного модификатора.

Так когда же надо использовать модификатор `u` а когда этого делать не требуется?

Comment: дополнительная функциональность указана после двоеточия: _шаблон и целевая строка обрабатываются как UTF-8 строки_

Comment: было бы неплохо еще ссылки на вопросы, в которых пример работы регулярок с UTF без модификатора `u`

Comment: @Grundy видимо ошибался, действительно не могу найти примеры конкретно с упоминанием utf. Но что странно в моем проекте регулярки без данного модификатора и работают.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать или нет модификатор `u` зависит от цели регулярного выражения и вашего умения в их составлении.

Вот пример в котором я разделяю строку (UTF-8) на две части: первый символ и все остальные:

```
<?php

$str = 'абвгд';

// модификатор есть
preg_match('%^(.)(.+)$%u', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

// модификатор нет
preg_match('%^(.)(.+)$%', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Результат работы:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "а"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "бвгд"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "�"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "�бвгд"
}
```

Тут регулярка без модификатора сработала с ошибкой, так как `.` без модификатора `u` соответствует 1 байту (а не символу) кроме байта x0D.

---

А теперь другой пример: получить подстроку между двумя скобками:

```
<?php

$str = 'прг[абвгд]ктм';

// модификатор есть
preg_match('%\[([^\]]*)\]%u', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

// модификатор нет
preg_match('%\[([^\]]*)\]%', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Результат работы:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "[абвгд]"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "[абвгд]"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
}
```

Оба варианта работают верно, так как символы `[` и `]` однозначно определены в кодировке UTF-8 и их коды не являются составной частью многобайтных символов.

**UPD**

> в зависимости от умения составления и в первом случае можно было получить результат без модификатора?

```
<?php

$str = 'abcde';

// модификатор нет
preg_match('%^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2})(.+)$%', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$str = 'абвгд';

// модификатор нет
preg_match('%^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2})(.+)$%', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

$str = 'Ⴀабвгд';

// модификатор нет
preg_match('%^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2})(.+)$%', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Результат работы:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "abcde"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "bcde"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "а"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "бвгд"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "Ⴀабвгд"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Ⴀ"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "абвгд"
}
```

Comment: в зависимости от умения составления и в первом случае можно было получить результат без модификатора?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, смотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: я понял, благодарю за развернутый ответ. Отличное извращение использовать коды символов))

Answer (score 0):

Когда будет unicode в строке с символами отличными от ASCI